# encrypted data retrieval for booking form

Tags: php, database, aes, encryption

Hi i have a booking system , which pulls data from  AES encrypted database. in the data base the postcode and the destination is encrypted, used to have an old script with list input, so users can select their destination on the list, since the destination list is getting big, i wanted to do a form in which users type in few letters and the destination comes up using ajax auto-fill. the problem i have is, its pulling, data as Encrypted.

the first booking script had this line to decrypt

```
$areafro = mysql_query("select AREA_NO, AES_DECRYPT(POSTCODE, 'qsi') as POSTCODE, AES_DECRYPT(AREA_NM, 'qsi') as AREA_NM from area_mst where AES_DECRYPT(POSTCODE, 'qsi') LIKE '$char%' group by POSTCODE");
```

this is the new booking script code

```
if(isset($_GET['areas']) && isset($_GET['letters'])){
$letters = $_GET['letters'];
$letters = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9 ]/si","",$letters);
$res = mysql_query("select POSTCODE,AREA_NM from area_mst where (POSTCODE like '".$letters."1' or AREA_NM like '".$letters."1') order by AREATYPE") or die(mysql_error();

while($inf = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    if($inf["POSTCODE"]!='')
    {
    echo $inf["POSTCODE"]."-".$inf["AREA_NM"]."|";
    }
    else
    {
    echo $inf["AREA_NM"]."|";
    }
}
```

could some one help me to how to get data decrypted ?

Answer (score 0):

Your query in the latter code does not decrypt. Notice in the old code, you have

```
$areafro = mysql_query("select AREA_NO, AES_DECRYPT(POSTCODE, 'qsi') as POSTCODE,
 AES_DECRYPT(AREA_NM, 'qsi') as AREA_NM from area_mst 
where AES_DECRYPT(POSTCODE, 'qsi') LIKE '$char%' group by POSTCODE");
```

But in the new code, you are simply extracting data without decrypting.

```
$res = mysql_query("select POSTCODE,AREA_NM from area_mst 
where (POSTCODE like '".$letters."1' or AREA_NM like '".$letters."1') 
order by AREATYPE")
```

Change your new code to have the query exactly as the one in the old code,